# Apache Virtual Host sem ServerName

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Quero montar um ambiente onde eu possa colocar minhas aplicações de produção (site1) e homologação (site2).

Então no meu servidor Ubuntu 15.10 eu montei da seguinte forma:

```
    - /var/www/html/site1
    - /var/www/html/site2
```

No /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
        Alias /site1 /var/www/html/site1

        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

No /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2
        Alias /site2 /var/www/html/site2

        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Sempre quando digito na URL localhost/site1, funciona perfeitamente. Mas quando digito localhost/site2, ele indica que não foi encontrado. Eu olhei o help do Apache e verifiquei a existência do ServerName, mas eu não possuo DNS. Então consigo configurar isso? Onde está meu erro?

Muito obrigado

Comment: Eu já tive problemas com o Ubuntu 15.10 para configurar Servidores Apache. Você tentou utilizar a 14.04? Apesar de ser uma versão mais antiga, já foi bem testada e homologada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lendo um pouco mais na internet e juntando com a resposta do @miguel-batista, o que funcionou foi colocar as duas aplicações no mesmo virtual host, diferenciando pelo *Alias*.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site.conf



<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /site1 /var/www/html/site1
    Alias /site2 /var/www/html/site2

    <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

É possível resolver seu problema da seguinte forma:

abra o arquivo `hosts` usuando o comando `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

e adicione as seguintes linhas no arquivo para criar o redirecionamento referente ao vhost que você quer criar:

```
127.0.1.1  site1
127.0.1.1  site2
```

em seguida abra o arquivo `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.conf` e edite os dados da seguinte forma

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName site1
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1

        <Directory /var/www/html/site1>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

para o site2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName site2
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2

        <Directory /var/www/html/site2>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

dessa forma você está criando um vhost para cada um e fazendo o apontamento para as pastas.

em seguida execute os comandos

```
a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site1.conf
a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site2.conf
```

para certificar que os dois vhosts estão abilitados no apache e em seguida

```
service apache2 restart
```

para acessar pela url não será necessário utilizar localhost

apenas `site1/` ou `site2/` você não precisa de um DNS para criar um servidor local utilizando o ServerName. Caso queira fazer em produção utilize o `IP de acesso ao servidor online/site1` ou `IP de acesso ao servidor online/site2`
espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Creio que a solução seja mesmo por ai, mas ainda ela não funcionou para a minha necessidade. Acabei não colocando alguns detalhes e pelo jeito isso faz a diferença. Minha aplicação interpreta a URL faz o roteamento. Por exemplo site1/Usuarios/novo chama a action novo dentro do controller de usuários... Acho que ainda está faltando a configuração do apache para fazer ele interpretar a URL. Seria o .htaccess?

Comment: você habilitou o modulo rewrite? com o comando sudo a2enmod rewrite e service apache2 restart, para interpretação de URL deve estar com o módulo rewrite ativo e sempre que utilizar o link coloque a url completa ou <a href="/usuario/novo">novo</a>

Comment: Habilitei sim. Ao entrar no site1 tudo vai bem. Ao entrar no site2 ele informa que a Url não existe.